# HTTP 406 Error While Logging In To DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I have a prototype WinForms application that uses open-source DocuSign.Integrations.Client library. It was working correctly until a couple of days ago. Now every attempt to login results in HTTP 406 error. No code has changed on my side, and my user name and password are valid (verified on https://appdemo.docusign.com). Any help is appreciated!

Below is the raw request with masked credentials:

```
GET http://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information?api_password=true&include_account_id_guid=true 
HTTP/1.1 Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>______</Username><Password>______</Password><IntegratorKey>____-________-___-___-___-____________</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Host: demo.docusign.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

In response, I get a 302 redirect:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-length: 0
Location: https://demo.docusign.net
Connection: close
```

And then receive a 406 error:

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 09 May 2015 19:16:52 GMT
Content-Length: 1346
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
http://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information?
api_password=true&include_account_id_guid=true
```

It should use HTTPS, not HTTP in your GET URL call:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information?
api_password=true&include_account_id_guid=true
```

Also your error is actually describes what is wrong

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
```

Your request headers should be this:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>______</Username><Password>______</Password><IntegratorKey>____-________-___-___-___-____________</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

Comment: Thank you, I switched to HTTPS and it started working again. I guess DocuSign made some change on their end because HTTP used to work...

Comment: I'm not aware of any changes, but you should ensure you use HTTPS for all calls through the DocuSign API.